# Vimeo crashes when appended by jQuery (but not YouTube)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, vimeo

When I use the following code Vimeo video fails to load but YouTube video loads fine:

```
var video_embed_code = 'my embed code as iframe goes here';
$('.container').html(video_embed_code);
```

I do this on click so document ready etc. doesn't matter here.

Here's the Vimeo result (Youtube works 100% fine with the same code, Vimeo WITHOUT jquery works 100% fine, too):
[image]

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery does all sorts of stuff to sanitize your HTML before inserting it, you can see here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L211

If you know your code is already clean and cross browser, then

```
$('.container')[0].innerHTML= video_embed_code;
```

will do just fine (and won't be slowed down either).

Comment: It returns the same page with the same broken Vimeo :) YouTube works with this method like before.

Comment: Hmm. Is vimeo_embed_code correct? try this: document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML= video_embed_code - if it doesn't work, my guess is that your problem is with vimeo_embed_code. Maybe add the code to the question and the browser you're using.

Comment: Update: You're right. There is something wrong with my code. It's complex thing and I just noticed "vimeo_embed_code" has wrong link after triggering that "click" event which embeds it. I'll let you know if it works once I fix that.

Comment: It worked! :) You were right that embed code was wrong. My script was adding image resizing to its URL. My initial example with `$('.container').html(slides);` works, too. Thanks!